# Search for unique cell and multiply row (Python Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large dataframe and I want to multiply a row with a unique value from another table.
To the column *value* I would like to search the second data frame (which is only those rows) for a match in my big dataframe and then multiply `big_frame.size` with `second_frame.price`

```
big_frame=
name year size *value*
v1  2015    5   50
v1  2015    5   50
v1  2015    5   50
v1  2015    5   50
v1  2016    5   75
v1  2016    5   75
v1  2016    5   75
v1  2016    5   75
v1  2016    5   75
v2  2015    4   36
v2  2015    4   36
v2  2015    4   36
v2  2016    4   100
v2  2016    4   100
v2  2016    4   100


second_frame = 
name year size price
v1   2015   5   10
v1   2016   5   15
v2   2015   4   9
v2   2016   4   25
```

I've tried using `.loc` to get the values but it complains that the frames aren't the same length. I would like to have something like excels lock function "$A$1" as I would rather not make a large frame to match `len(big_frame)` for each value since the big_frame is a big one.

Adding a column with the price in big_frame and then multiply would also be an acceptable solution (although imo, that would slow down the process, right?)
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could created a merged df using `merge` which will merge on all columns and perform an inner merge so only exact matches will remain and then just multiply the 2 columns:

```
In [6]:
merged = df1.merge(df2)
merged

Out[6]:
   name  year  size  price
0    v1  2015     5     10
1    v1  2015     5     10
2    v1  2015     5     10
3    v1  2015     5     10
4    v1  2016     5     15
5    v1  2016     5     15
6    v1  2016     5     15
7    v1  2016     5     15
8    v1  2016     5     15
9    v2  2015     4      9
10   v2  2015     4      9
11   v2  2015     4      9
12   v2  2016     4     25
13   v2  2016     4     25
14   v2  2016     4     25

In [7]:
merged['value'] = merged['size'] * merged['price']
merged

Out[7]:
   name  year  size  price  value
0    v1  2015     5     10     50
1    v1  2015     5     10     50
2    v1  2015     5     10     50
3    v1  2015     5     10     50
4    v1  2016     5     15     75
5    v1  2016     5     15     75
6    v1  2016     5     15     75
7    v1  2016     5     15     75
8    v1  2016     5     15     75
9    v2  2015     4      9     36
10   v2  2015     4      9     36
11   v2  2015     4      9     36
12   v2  2016     4     25    100
13   v2  2016     4     25    100
14   v2  2016     4     25    100
```

Comment: This worked well, thank you. I would like to add that for my actual frame it created a problem as I had more data in there, it worked perfectly when when adding `merged = df1.merge(df2, on = ['x', 'y'])`

Comment: by default it will match on all columns, if you pass a list of cols then the default type of merge is inner so only exact matches are kept in the merge